# How do I make the first child of my div to appear behind the div?

Tags: html, css

I have been wrestling with my z-indexing for many hours now. I've read a lot about how stacking contexts change but it must be going over my head because I can't get this basic example to work.

The html:

```
<div class="container">
       <a href="#" class="under">under</a> 
<a href="#" class="over">over</a>


</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.container{
    float: left;
background:red
z-index: 1; 
padding-top: 20px;
text-align: center;
margin-top: 50px;
color: white;

    background:red;
    position:fixed;
}

.over{
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
float: left;
}

.under{
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
float: left; 
position: relative;
float: left;
top: -20px;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

The fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/jpo0y2sL/

I cant get the link "under" to appear behind the background of the container div.

Answer (score 1):

You are writing little bit more complicated styles. Basically, any child couldn't be behind it's parent but in your case, if you want to achieve it, there shouldn't be any position on parent div (.container). You can achieve it with following example style:

```
.container {
    border:1px solid green;
    background-color: #ccc;
}
.under, .over {
    position:relative;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}
.under {
    border:1px solid black;
    z-index: -1;
    }
.over {
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the link a div to make it easy to control by css.

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="under"><a href="#">under</a> </div>
   <div class="over"><a href="#" >over</a></div>
</div>

.over{
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 float: left;
 top: -20px;
 z-index:2;
}

.under{
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 float: left;
 top: -20px;
 z-index:1;
}
```

Is it what you wanna do to overlap both of your link?

Comment: OP is trying to make `.under` go behind the `.container` background

Comment: by this way you will not seeing .under cause .container is a solid color, however, u can still add in (background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);) for .container css to make your .container having opacity, but your .under link will not clickable because it been block by .container

Comment: Yes, that's what I want. It seems silly to have my a tag not clickable but I am then moving it with javascript. So @haxxxton was right. and this example doesn't work for me in that regard.

Answer (score 0):

Other than the missing semicolon and repeating `background` properties, your real problem stems from giving `.container` a z-index in the first place. This code worked for me without the need of creating a `<div>` burger:

```
<div class="container">
    <a href="#" id="under">under</a> 
    <a href="#" class="over">over</a>
</div>

.container{
position: fixed;
background: red;
padding-top: 20px;
text-align: center;
margin-top: 50px;
color: white;
}
.over{
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
float: left;
position: relative;
}
#under{
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
position: relative;
top: -20px;
z-index: -1;
}
```

As an added note, you cannot float and position elements at the same time.

Comment: Hmm, it seems my solution works in Firefox but not Chrome. Give me a minute.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="#" class="under">under</a>
 <div class="container">
  <a href="#" class="over">over</a>
 </div>

.container{
 position: fixed;
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
 z-index:0;
}
.over{
 float: left;
 width:100%;
}
.under{
 width:100%;
 float: left;
 z-index:-1;
 color:orange;
}
```

try this